# compilation error in CGAL4.10 - DBL_MAX in CGAL AABB_traits.h

Tags: c++11, cgal, aabb

I am using CGAL's AABB for my project. I had no problem with CGAL3.9. But, now I am using a cluster which has CGAL4.10. When I compile my code, I get the following error.

```
/apps/cgal/4.10/gnu/include/CGAL/AABB_traits.h:125:20: error: 'DBL_MAX' was not declared in this scope

    FT t_near = -DBL_MAX; // std::numeric_limits<FT>::lowest(); C++1903
```

I know that DBL_MAX is defined in `<cfloat>` (or float.h) but I can not edit the CGAL source in the cluster as I don't have root privileges.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can include cfloat early in your program, without changing the CGAL headers.

Comment: Thank you, Marc. It did not work. I placed <cfloat> as the first header file in my code. I got the same error. How does CGAL AABB see DBL_MAX if I place the header in my file? Doesn't the header file have to be in the file where DBL_MAX is used?

Comment: After struggling for a couple of hours, I finally solved this. I defined DBL_MAX (using #define DBL_MAX    1.7976931348623157E+308
) before adding CGAL header files. It worked.

Comment: No, includes don't have to be in the file where they are used. It is very suspicious that including cfloat first in your program did not work. Quite possibly you are doing something wrong when compiling.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was adding CGAL folder to the include path while compiling my code. Once I removed it, I could compile successfully without having to define DBL_MAX.

Comment: In CGAL-4.11 we have added a mechanism specifically to detect this error: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/1807

Comment: I think that is a very good error checking mechanism. It would save a lot of time.